# Why Iroha Consensus takes seconds?

Tags: hyperledger, consensus, hyperledger-iroha

I'm doing some scalability testing with hyperledger Iroha using docker containers. Therefore I increase the number of nodes within the network step by step, write some transactions into the ledger an determine the average latency for transaction processing.
The problem is that around 30 nodes the consensus seems to stop working properly i.e. it takes seconds until a transaction is committed.

I have already tried to vary some configuration parameters like vote delay but this does not change irohas behavior.

This my configuration for the iroha nodes:

```
{
  "block_store_path" : "/tmp/block_store/",
  "torii_port" : 50051,
  "internal_port" : 10001,
  "pg_opt" : "host=some-postgres port=5432 user=postgres password=password1234",
  "max_proposal_size" : 50,
  "proposal_delay" : 5000,
  "vote_delay" : 5000,
  "mst_enable" : false,
  "mst_expiration_time" : 1440,
  "max_rounds_delay": 50,
  "stale_stream_max_rounds": 2
}
```

Which sometimes leads to transaction processing times of around 10 seconds: https://gist.github.com/dltuser12/913e036efd735b2996d387b1423096c9 (Iroha Log file for a corresponding example)

Comment: It is not answer, but here You have described Iroha's consensus algorithm: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/327434229_YAC_BFT_Consensus_Algorithm_for_Blockchain, so mayby You will find answer for Your question thanks to the document.